# Tags: space-law vs. international-law

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms, retagging

I've started on the tagging, and I've already noticed two related tags: [space-law](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/space-law) and [international-law](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/international-law).  The few questions I've noticed could be tagged with either, as far as I can tell.

1. Are we going to pick one? If so:
2. Which one will it be?
3. Or would [law](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/law) make more sense?

Comment: [space-law] has the advantage of sounding really awesome

Answer (score 3):

I'm thinking [international-law](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/international-law) should be for questions relating to laws that are not specifically for space, whereas [space-law](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/space-law) should be used for questions relating to laws that were specifically drafted for space.

Example:

- Anti-Ballistic Missile Treaty would be [international-law](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/international-law)
  because it is also for fully ground based weaponry, not just space
  based weaponry.
- Outer Space Treaty would be [space-law](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/space-law) because
  it was specifically written and only applies to actions in space.

Comment: Under that definition, wouldn't every question tagged international-law, but not space-law, be off-topic?

Comment: @Gwenn the activities in space not being the subject of space law, can be still subject of international law, for example when it comes to crimes committed outside the territory of any state.

Comment: Fundamentally, this is a site about space. I don't think there is enough difference between space law and international law to warrant their own tag, simply having law seems adequate.

Answer (score 3):

The asker makes good points, and I don't see the need to split up the tag which will probably be 99% [space-law](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/space-law) and 1% [international-law](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/international-law). I suggest we just use [law](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/law).

Comment: This seems particularly appropriate since one might have *national* (or more local) laws which are not specifically about space (e.g., use of radio frequencies) but which can influence operations in space.