# Difference between [law], [regulatory] and [international-politics] tags? The last two have no use guidance, what might that be?

Tags: discussion, support, tags, tagging

- [law](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/law) **117** questions:

> Relating to treaties, laws, ownership and disputes during the exploration of space. For non-space exploration related law questions, see our sister site Law Stack Exchange.

- [regulatory](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/regulatory) **50** questions:

> The regulatory tag has no usage guidance, can you help us create it?

- [international-politics](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/international-politics) **40** questions:

> The international-politics tag has no usage guidance, can you help us create it?

Without any usage guidance it's currently hard to say what the scopes of the regulatory and international-politics tags are and how they differentiate from the law tag. In fact I'm not 100% sure what the difference is between laws and regulations. I am guessing that laws give authority to entities to write and enforce regulations through fines and license revocations, and laws don't?

**Question:** What is the difference between the [law](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/law), [regulatory](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/regulatory) and [international-politics](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/international-politics) tags? What would be good usage guidance for the last two that would clearly distinguish all three from each other so that we might not just use some mixture because we aren't always sure which ones to use?

---

To [Would it be legal for a company to build a base on Luna?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/54309/12102) I've added [law](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/law), [regulatory](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/regulatory) and [international-politics](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/international-politics) without confidence as to how much each of these applies to the question. The title says "law" but I'll bet the OP will be interested in what international treaties say about this as well.

Related:

- [Would a “space-governance” new tag be of interest?](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1817/12102)  from June 2021
- [Tags: space-law vs. international-law](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5/12102) Space Meta SE question # 5 from 2013
- [Should [space-law] be just [law]?](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/q/168/12102) Space Meta SE question # 168 from 2013
- [Space law and Stack Exchange policy on legal advice](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/q/164/12102) Space Meta SE question # 164 from 2013

Answer (score 4):

My opinion: [law](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/law) and [regulatory](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/regulatory) should be made synonyms. What's the difference?

But [international-politics](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/international-politics) is a very different matter because now we're having to deal with treaties. Except when we're not. It is a bit murky. For example, the US Congress has banned NASA from having any dealings with China. That's the  [law](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/law).

On the other hand, there's the relation between Russia and the US regarding the International Space Station. This [international-politics](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/international-politics) relationship was intentionally created to hopefully overcome political differences.